# Use same int for two different loops

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to create a simple lottery game:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random gen = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter desired numbers to be drawn");
    int print = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter desired numbers on dice");
    int dice = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your lucky numbers");
    for(int i=1; i<=print;i++){
        int num = scan.nextInt();
    }
    int randnum;
    if (randnum == num){
        System.out.println("Winner winner chicken dinner!");

    }
    for(int counter=1; counter<=print;counter++){
        randnum = 1+gen.nextInt(dice);
        System.out.println(randnum + " ");

    }
}
```

}

Problem is that *int num* cannot be resolved to variable in the if loop.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare `int num` before the loop. You will need to initialize it so that it is definitely assigned in case the loop body does not execute:

```
int num = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=print;i++){
    num = scan.nextInt();
}
```

However, it seems like you are trying to collect more than one number. Your loop reads `print` numbers and only remembers the last. You might consider creating an array:

```
int[] numbers = new int[print];
for(int i=0; i<print;i++){
    numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `int num` before the loop and assign the value inside of the loop

```
int num = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=print;i++) {
    num = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `num` in the scope of the `for loop` so it can't be accessed outside the `for loop`.  Take a look at java scopes...Also you might want to move your `if(randum == num)` to after the second for loop because at that point randum has not been initialized...

Comment: Thanks. Moved it after the second loop. it doesn't print you win when in fact you lost